# How would you aces this highlighted section in html source code using selenium when driver.find returns empty []

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

Website Source Code:

[image]

I am trying to reach the highlighted source code using seleniums driver.find_elements
Ive tried the xpath(/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/ul/li[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBcPy.png)/a[3]), by class name and by tag but they all return an empty [] any tips on how I could aces that page?

Comment: Cannot help with xPath ands suggest to not use it. Try with tagName ```driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')``` or css_selector ```driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')```

Comment: Yeah I'm not committed to xPath its just that they are all giving me the same results which is an empty []

Comment: This code might be inside an ```iframe``` tag with you need to switch to first. More info on iframe here: https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html. Any chance you can share the full html or website?

Comment: I see! Of course the website is https://www.sicop.go.cr/index.jsp since its a dynamic website I figured selenium was the best but Im trying to scrape the listings under the "Concursos" tabs which according to googles developer tool the highlighted html above corresponds to that tab.  Im just having trouble accessing the listings on that page using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

The content you are trying to reach is inside an `iframe`

You need to switch to it first using:

`driver.switch_to.frame(0)`

0 is the index of the iframe in your case.

Then you should be able to retrieve the list of `a` tag using:

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

You will need to switch back to the default frame if you need to interact with the rest of the page:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

More info on iframe with selenium [here](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)